# Date ranges on react-native-modal-datetime-picker?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to implement a the `react-native-modal-datetime-picker`, I know isn't possible to select a range of times but theres any work around for dates? let the user select from 1 of feb to 2 of mar?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try minimumDate and maximumDate props of type Date ? ( works only with date for android , no time ) , And it's work properly on IOS

Comment: Hi, I know you could set a minimum and maximum date range but I meant select a date range from the user side, not restrict the possible dates.

Comment: Unfortunately  you can't do this using react-native-modal-datetime-picker , i would suggest this  : https://github.com/lazaronixon/react-native-date-range-picker , You will have some cool features as marked Dates.